# Match String and Get Variable PHP

Tags: php, preg-match

I would like to be able to use this string to pull off a certain piece of data from a database '{my-id-1}' so basically if this is found in the text '{my-id-*}' then get the id (eg. if {is-id-1} then ID is 1) and then I can run some code with that ID.

So I've got it so I can get the ID from the braces, but I'm not sure how to replace that within the text.

```
<?php
$text = "test 1 dfhjsdh sdjkfhksdhfkj skjh {is-id-1} sdfhskdfh sdfsdjfhksd fjksdfhksd {is-id-2}";
preg_match_all('/{is-id-+(.*?)}/',$text, $matches);
print_r ($matches);

$replacewiththis = "this has been replaced, it was id: " . $idhere;
$text = preg_replace('/{is-id-+(.*?)}/', $replacewiththis, $text);

echo $text;
?>
```

The Array for the matches outputs:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
    [0] => {is-id-1} 
    [1] => {is-id-2} 
  ) 
  [1] => Array ( 
    [0] => 1 
    [1] => 2 
  ) 
)
```

I'm stuck now and not sure how to can process each of the braces. Can anyone give me a hand?

Thanks.

Comment: The returned `$matches` is an array of 2 arrays, the first one is the matches and the second one is the `ID` you want. (so `$matches[0][0] => 1 , $matches[0][1] => 2`)
The function returns all the matches , not just one , so you'll need a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understood well what you want, but I think this is it:

```
foreach($matches[1] as $match){
  $replacewiththis = "this has been replaced, it was id: $match";
  $text=str_replace('{is-id-'.$match.'}', $replacewiththis, $text);
}
echo $text;
```