# PHP Match String Pattern and Get Variable

Tags: php, regex

I looked up some reference like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710286/match-string-and-get-variable-php) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943913/php-match-string-and-get-the-rest) but could not figure out what I need to do.

What I am trying to do is:

Say, I have two strings:

```
$str1 = "link/usa";
$str2 = "link/{country}";
```

Now I want to check if this the pattern matches. If they match, I want the value of country to be set usa.

```
$country = "usa";
```

I also want it to work in cases like:

```
$str1 = "link/usa/texas";
$str2 = "link/{country}/{place}";
```

Maybe integers as well. Like match every braces and provide the variable with value. (And, yes better performance if possible)

I cannot get a work around since I am very new to regular expresssions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will give you results as expected

```
$str1 = "link/usa";
$str2 = "link/{country}";

if(preg_match('~link/([a-z]+)~i', $str1, $matches1) && preg_match('~link/{([a-z]+)}~i', $str2, $matches2)){
    $$matches2[1] = $matches1[1];
    echo $country;
}
```

Note: Above code will just parse alphabets, you can extend characters in range as per need.

**UPDATE:**

You can also do it using [`explode`](http://www.php.net/Explode), see example below:

```
$val1 = explode('/', $str1);
$val2 = explode('/', $str2);
${rtrim(ltrim($val2[1],'{'), '}')} = $val1[1];
echo $country;
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
$str1 = "link/usa/texas/2/";
$str2 = "/link/{country}/{city}/{page}";

if(preg_match_all('~/([a-z0-9]+)~i', $str1, $matches1) && preg_match_all('~{([a-z]+)}~i', $str2, $matches2)){

    foreach($matches2[1] as $key => $matches){
        $$matches = $matches1[1][$key];
    }
    echo $country; 
    echo '<br>';
    echo $city;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $page;
}
```

Comment: How about the performance? Can I depend on this looping maybe a hundred times?

Comment: hundred times, no big deal, try it

Comment: @tika you can also do it using `explode`, if you would like to avoid regex, see my updated answer

Comment: That works for the set example, but for `/link/usa/texas/2/` type of links?
Maybe the pattern be: `/link/{country}/{city}/{page}`. Please see that I have updated the question. I do not want the `preg_match(~link)` to be hard-coded.

Comment: `${rtrim(ltrim($val2[1],'{'), '}')}` => `${trim($val2, '{}')}` is more simple.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte `$val2` is an array, which also doesn't contain the value to be assigned as required, Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Sorry, I have forgotten the `[1]`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the point to use the key as variable name when you can built an associative array that will be probably more handy to use later and that avoids to write ugly dynamic variable names `${the_name_of_the_var_${of_my_var_${of_your_var}}}`:

```
$str1 = "link/usa/texas";
$str2 = "link/{country}/{place}";

function combine($pattern, $values) {
    $keys = array_map(function ($i) { return trim($i, '{}'); },
                      explode('/', $pattern));
    $values = explode('/', $values);

    if (array_shift($keys) == array_shift($values) && count($keys) &&
        count($keys) == count($values))
        return array_combine($keys, $values);
    else throw new Exception ("invalid format");
}

print_r(combine($str2, $str1));
```